# one way sensitivity analysis with categorical variable

Tags: excel, math, statistics

I am studying the impact of different factors on the expected price change for drugs. I have a regression model that looks like the following: *Y=a+B1x1+B2x2...* I would like to conduct some one-way sensitivity analysis in order to see which predictors have the biggest impact on the price change.
I have two questions concerning the sensitivity analysis:

1. I am applying a ±30% variation on the numerical variables to investigate 
   the impact on the price change. However, what is the
   best practice for categorical variables?

   What I have done so far is that I created a dummy variable for each
   level of the categorical variable.  If you consider for instance the
   country variable (one of my predictors), I basically investigate the
   impact of changing from the reference value (say UK) to Italy for
   the categorical variable Country at the level Italy. This
   interpretation is basically equivalent to the regression
   coefficient.

   Is my approach correct or would you have any other suggestion?

   I attach an extract of my output Tornado chart here [tornado chart
   extract](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qIjt.png)
2. In case I have some numerical variables that are equal to 0 at a base case 
   any ±30% variation will still result in a null variable. How could I 
   overcome this problem without simply setting arbitrary values?

Many thanks your help is very much appreciated

Best

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark where would my question then be more appropriate? thanks

Comment: @Zandre [stats.se] would be a natural choice